# How to end editing mode of a TableView after first responder was called on a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a simple program where you can add "cells" with `UITextFields` (ergo they are editable) with the help of a 'add Button' in the "edit mode" of a `TableView`.

When pressing the return key I want that the program 'jumps out' of the editing mode to the 'normal' Table View.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you setup the user interface for your app in a `xib` or `storyboard`? So, make sure you connect the delegate outlet of the `UITextField` to your (view) controller and implement the delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn:` there:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can end the editing in the table view by using the method **setEditing:animated:**

```
[self.tableView setEditing:No animated:YES];
```

You would do it inside the textField delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if(self.tableview.editing){
      [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }

    return NO; 
}
```

You have **setEditing:animated:** method and **editing** property on UIViewController itself. So, you could do it from those properties as well like;

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        if(self.editing){
          [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        }

        return NO; 
    }
```